# Google Speech API Deprecated?

Tags: api, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, google-speech-api

I've been looking around for a speech recognition API to use in my application. It is not a mobile or web app and instead needs to integrate with cloud speech from native code such as Java, C# or C++.  Looking around the web it appears that Google had an experimental API available in API console but I cannot seem to find it.  I'm wondering if it has been deprecated?  I couldn't find anything from Google confirming this hypothesis.

Any suggestions on where to get high quality cloud speech?

Comment: This isn't really the place to ask for opinions. Also just saying deprecated code can be found. Google wouldn't have just deleted it all of the sudden.

Answer (score 0):

You need a TTS api?

here is it, you can read the code and write in your likely language.

https://github.com/hiddentao/google-tts

Answer (score 0):

Join the https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/chromium-dev

Then you can get a API key from console.cloud.google.com after you joined the group.